How do you make the environment persist across jobs in GitHub Actions?
This question is a follow-up to this question, where I learned that writes to GITHUB_ENV do not persist across jobs. If $GITHUB_ENV will only affect subsequent steps  in the same job, then how do we work around this? I want a dependent job to makes changes to $GITHUB_ENV which subsequent jobs will inherit.

Using $GITHUB_OUTPUT

Write to GITHUB_OUTPUT$: This is the only supported method to pass data between jobs
myenvprep:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Prepare Environment
      id: myenvprep
      run: |
        echo "mykey=myvalue" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"


Export the output variable by mapping the output variable to the job's outputs:: This makes the key mykey available to be stored in an output variable; but, you must still export that output variable. To do that you need to add something like this to the job.
myenvprep:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  outputs:
    myoutput: ${{ steps.myenvprep.outputs.mykey }}
  steps:
    - name: Prepare Environment
      id: myenvprep
      run: |
        echo "mykey=myvalue" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"


Map the output variable to the job's env: now you can reference the output in the env: declaration for subsequent jobs,
otherjob:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: myenvprep
  steps:
    - name: Retrieve Env
      env:
        MYKEY: ${{ needs.myenvprep.outputs.myoutput }}
      run: |
        echo $MYKEY



Distinct Names for Everything
So an MVE of this looks like this, but the names are only kept distinct for demonstration. In production, you'd likely just use env for all these distinct names (demonstrated below)
on: push

jobs:
  myenvprep:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      myoutput: ${{ steps.myenvprep.outputs.mykey }}
    steps:
      - name: Prepare Environment
        id: myenvprep
        run: |
          echo "mykey=myvalue" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  otherjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: myenvprep
    steps:
      - name: Retrieve Env
        env:
          MYKEY: ${{ needs.myenvprep.outputs.myoutput }}
        run: |
          echo $MYKEY

Collapsing Names for Simplicity
That the names were kept distinct is just to illustrate the concept. This is how it should look in production,
on: push

jobs:
  env:
    name: Generate Environment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      mykey: ${{ steps.env.outputs.mykey }}
    steps:
      - name: Prepare And Save Environment
        id: env
        run: |
          echo "mykey=myvalue" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  build:
    name: Do Buildy Things
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: env
    steps:
      - name: Retreive Env
        env:
          MYKEY: ${{ needs.env.outputs.mykey }}
        run: |
          echo $MYKEY

